# Help maintenance & repair

Tags: pontiac, fuel-injectors, g6

06 Pontiac g6 will not start! I recently changed fuel pump. I am getting fuel to the fuel rail with pressure but fuel injectors are not opening. I can pour gas in the breather and it will start until the gas stops. Please help

Comment: Either the injectors are not receiving electric signals telling them to function or the injectors are all stuck shut ( perhaps after sitting for a long period of time). Whats the usage history of the vehicle?  Mileage?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Have you checked the fuse to the injectors?

Comment: What engine? 2.4, 3.5, or 3.9

Comment: 2 possibilities, theft deterrent system is active, crank position sensor is defective.